# Find files of specific file types using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, file, find

I have a requirement to recursively loop through all the files of certain file types in a directory. The file types is an array variable containing the list of file types that we need to go through for processing. The array values are actually dynamically populated. For the sake of simplicity I am declaring a static array.

```
 declare -a arr=("pdf" "doc" "txt")
```

I have the following code to recursively list all the files in the directory, but I am not able to figure out how include the array "arr" to only get back those file types that are included in the array.

```
find $i -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do
    echo $file;
    #Process file
done
```

Please help me modify the code so that I could retrieve the specified file types only and not all files.

Comment: [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/126290/find-files-filtered-by-multiple-extensions) on the Superuser SE site may be of help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that by file types "pdf", "doc", "txt",
you mean filenames with those extensions.

If the number of file types is reasonably small (less than a few dozen),
then you could build an array of arguments to pass to `find` in the format:

```
... -name '*.pdf' -o -name '*.doc' -o -name '*.txt' ...
```

Assuming that the array of file types is not empty, here's one way to do it (thanks [@mike-holt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3307686/mike-holt)):

```
arr=(pdf doc txt)

findargs=()

for t in "${arr[@]}"; do
    findargs+=(-name "*.$t" -o)
done

find . -type f \( "${findargs[@]}" -false \)
```

Comment: I like that way too.

Answer (score 4):

What you will need to do is dynamically build a *regex* from your array of types (presuming *extensions*) to pass to `find` with the `-regex` option. `find` can then use the `regex` to find filenames that match. Given your example, you are wanting to build a *regex* similar to:

```
"^.*[.]\(pdf\|doc\|txt\)$"
```

In order to build that regex dynamically from the array content, you can do something similar to the following

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=(pdf doc txt)   ## dynamically built array of extensions
n=${#arr[@]}        ## number of elements in array
regex='^.*[.]\('    ## beginning of regex
srch="${1:-.}"      ## path to search (default '.')

for ((i = 0; i < $n; i++)); do  ## loop over each element
    ## if not last, add "${arr[i]}\|" otherwise add "${arr[i]}\)"
    ((i < n - 1)) && regex="$regex${arr[i]}\|" || regex="$regex${arr[i]}\)"
done

regex="$regex\$"    ## add the final '$'

find "$srch" -type f -regex "$regex"  ## execute the find
```

(**note** this uses a bash specific C-style for loop and arrays so it is not POSIX shell portable -- which since you are using an array shouldn't be a problem)

Give it a try and let me know if that meets your needs.

Comment: Or you could just do `find \( $(printf -- "-name *.%s -o " "${arr[@]}") -false \)`

Comment: Yes, that looks like an easier approach using `-name` and `-o` as @janos answered with. I took the Rube Goldberg *regex* approach `:)`

Comment: @MikeHolt the `*` may get expanded by the shell. It's not very safe. But I got a tip from you in `-false` and greatly improved my answer with it, thanks!

Comment: @janos Hmm. Seems you're right. It fails if any of the types in `arr` are present in the top-level directory. So yeah, you'd either have to construct an array of arguments as in your answer, or use `set -o noglob` first. I'm just a sucker for one-liners. :-)